# Alternate forms libraries on django eg sprox, formalchemy

Tags: django, django-forms, sqlalchemy, formalchemy, sprox

Has anyone had any joy/pain with using other form libraries in django projects (with SQLAlchemy models initially, but perhaps to use with django models in future)?

Initial impressions are that sprox is more flexible and decoupled but that formalchemy might be quicker to get up and running with, but I'd be really interested in hearing from other people who have defected from django.forms already or that have experience with either of sprox or formalchemy.

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 2):

We have used `django.newforms` a lot and tried formalchemy in toy examples.  Probably we have no-so-common needs (creating a huge amount of forms for rich convenient  administrative interface). Both were a pain to use. We didn't try sprox, but it doesn't look promising. That's why we designed our [own forms library](http://bitbucket.org/ods/insanities/). It's already used in production for quite enough time to prove its usefulness. Try it if you have similar needs, you are OK with missing documentations and don't hesitate to contact developers.